# reserving first and last two files and moving the rest to a different destination

Tags: powershell

I want to reserve first and last two files and moving the rest to a different destination, please assist.

Eg : my folder contains files: file1,file2,file3...file9,file10 so file1,file9 and file10 must remain and the rest moved to the destination folder.

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide a code you tried and didnt work

Comment: $_filesSource = "C:\Data"
$_UnreservedFilesDestination = "C:\MovedFiles"


$_Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $_filesSource -File -Force -Recurse


foreach ($file in $_Files)
{
 
      $FileNo = $file.Name.Substring(4,1)
       
      If((1 -ne $FileNo) or (9 -ne $FileNo) or (10 -ne $HeatNo) ) 
       {
          
          Move-item $file.FullName -destination $_UnreservedFilesDestination 
          
       
       }
}

Comment: This code will move the rest of the files and leave file1,file9,file10 but now if the files are name eg : file2...to file16 , i will then need to reserve file2,file15,file16. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Please take a look at how to write a question and code snipet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

No need to test anything, just skip the files you don't need (the first and the two last ones) :

```
$_filesSource = "C:\Data"
$_UnreservedFilesDestination = "C:\MovedFiles"

# You cannot use -Skip and -SkipLast in the same call
$_Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $_filesSource -File -Force -Recurse |
          Select-Object -Skip 1 | Select-Object -SkipLast 2
$_Files | Move-Item -Destination $_UnreservedFilesDestination
```

if you don't need to keep track of your files, you can do this shorter :

```
$_filesSource = "C:\Data"
$_UnreservedFilesDestination = "C:\MovedFiles"

# You cannot use -Skip and -SkipLast in the same call
Get-ChildItem -Path $_filesSource -File -Force -Recurse |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 | Select-Object -SkipLast 2 | 
    Move-Item -Destination $_UnreservedFilesDestination
```